# How long can I keep a dessert out of the fridge?

Tags: food-safety, dessert

Recently an uncle of mine taught me how to make [Γαλακτομπούρεκο](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaktoboureko), which contains eggs and milk. When I asked him how many hours after it is baked should I put it the fridge, he said that it is Ok for a couple of days out of fridge.

But I'm not really sure, since it contains milk and eggs, like I said. So, how long is a dessert like this good for out of fridge without it getting bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is a custard, you should probably refrigerate it as soon as it is cool.

A very sugary or acidic custard may be able to resist bacteria for a couple days (see Bismark donuts), but unless the recipe was specifically developed to be stable at room temperature, then there is some risk of it going bad.

If you have a fridge, there's no reason not to use it.  It may make the dough a little soggy, so you will want to find a way to store it to reduce condensation.

Better yet, make just as much as you are going to eat/serve at one time, and don't worry about this problem.

[Link 1 (search for custard on page)](http://food.unl.edu/safety/chart)

[Link 2 (about pies, see portion on Custard pies)](http://shelflifeadvice.com/content/how-long-can-pie-be-left-unrefrigerated)

Answer (score 3):

The short and clear answer is: it is absolutely not safe. As with any cooked food, the official safe period is 4 hours outside of the fridge. That's it, no matter if you have eggs, or anything else inside.

I'm aware that many people don't care for the official guidelines, and go by feeling and food type, and that's their right. But there is no way to give an answer for how long it will be "good" by these criteria, it is a subjective gut feeling. If you want to take the risk, take it. Nobody can tell you how large it really is, only that you are risking food poisoning if you do it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure cooked hard tack is safe left out indefinitely.

Comment: @Joshua there are foods which are intended to be shelf-stable, and we tend to call the process of their creation "cooking", so yes, "all cooked food" is technically incorrect here. There are exceptions. My point was that, when you cook a standard meal (as opposed to preparing a specific shelf-stable product), you have to take the danger zone into account. If you know a better way to word it, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I think different prepared foods inherently have different counter safety times.

Comment: @Joshua then you are incorrect. Prepared are either shelf-stable, or they aren't. If they are not shelf-stable, the danger zone of 4 hours (2 if you bought it) applies.